# LibGDX AssetManager not loading anything

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have recently added an AssetManager class to my LibGDX game, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my AssetManager class:

```
public class AssetLoader {

    public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public void loadAssets(){
        manager.load("antoanimation.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("antoButton.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("bg2.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("bottomtube2.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("clickme.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("diamtermopan.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("gameover.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("grass.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("logo.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("menubutton.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("pausebutton.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("pausemenu.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("play.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("restartbutton.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("return.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("selected.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("shopbutton.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("shopLayout.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("termopanButton.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("vladanimation.png", Texture.class);
        manager.load("vladButton.png", Texture.class);
    }



    public void dispose(){
        manager.dispose();
    }
```

This is my main game class:

```
    public class FlappyPela extends ApplicationAdapter {
        public static SpriteBatch batch;
        private GameStateManager gsm;
        private AssetLoader assets;


        @Override
        public void create () {
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            gsm = new GameStateManager();
            assets = new AssetLoader();
            assets.loadAssets();
            assets.manager.finishLoading();
            gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));
        }



        @Override
        public void render() {
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            super.render();




        }
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            super.dispose();
            assets.manager.dispose();
            batch.dispose();
        }
        }
```

And this is my Menu class:

```
public class MenuState extends State {
    private Texture background;
    private Sprite logo;
    private Sprite clickme;
    PlayButton play;
    Viewport viewport;



public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    background = new Texture("bg2.png");
    play = new PlayButton();
    logo = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("logo.png")));
    clickme = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("clickme.png")));
    viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280, cam);
    viewport.apply();
    cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.viewportHeight / 2,0);
    logo.setSize(620, cam.viewportHeight / 2 - 200);
    logo.setPosition(cam.viewportWidth / 2 - logo.getWidth() / 2 , cam.viewportHeight / 2 + 100);
    clickme.setSize(460, 450);
    clickme.setPosition(225, 125);

}

@Override
public void handleInput() {
    if(play.isPressed()){
        gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
    }

}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
    cam.update();

}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height){
     viewport.update(width, height);
     cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.viewportHeight / 2,0);
}


@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    cam.update();
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(background, 0, 0, cam.viewportWidth, cam.viewportHeight);
    logo.draw(sb);
    clickme.draw(sb);
    sb.end();
    play.act();
    play.draw();

}
@Override
public void dispose() {
    background.dispose();
    logo.getTexture().dispose();
    clickme.getTexture().dispose();
}
```

}

When I start the emulator, it just shows a black screen, and then my entire program crashes! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your crashes report ?

Comment: you are not using/getting  data from AssetManger that you created.

Comment: Also i need code of your State Class ?

Comment: It doesn't give me a crash report. Also, the State class is not relevant in this situation, since the app worked fine before I started using the AssetManager.

Comment: can you tell me where you are using AssetManager in MenuState class.

Answer (score 0):

## You are only queuing elements

the `AssetManager.load()` methods only adds a "loadable" resource to it, but doesn't actually load it. To do that, you need to call `AssetManager.update()`

Then it loads your resources, be loading one by one for each call to `update()`.

Try this:

```
public void render() {
      if(manager.update()) {
         // we are done loading, let's move to another screen!
      }

      // display loading information
      float progress = manager.getProgress()
      ... left to the renderer, display loading bar or somthing ...
}
```

You could then display a loading bar indicator or something while `manager.update()` returns false.

Note that the framerate is very low during loading, as stuff needs be loaded in the GL Thread in order to have correct access to the GL context. But during your initial loading screen, this shouldn't matter, as long as there is a loading bar, so the user doesn't think the game is stuck.